# Authenticating to Spring Security after authenticating to Twitter / Facebook

Tags: grails, facebook, spring-security, twitter, twitter4j

I have a grails app configured with spring-security-core and I need to allow Facebook / Twitter logins.  I'm using the facebook plugin for grails and I'm using twitter4j for twitter authentication.  Currently, I am successfully authenticating against Twitter and Facebook.

I'm wondering how I am to integrate those logins with Spring security.  If a user logs in with Twitter I am assuming I need to create an account in my database and then use that account to process a login for Spring Security so that it wires up the session appropriately and all the authentication checks happen based on my @Secured annotations and tag usage in my views.

Something similar, I am guessing, needs to happen based on Facebook logins.  Can someone point me in the right direction to get this implemented correctly?

Comment: Here's a similar question, although it hasn't had an accepted answer yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377244/trying-to-use-grails-spring-security-plugin-facebook-connect-to-automatically-c

Comment: The thread helped.  I think I know how to go about it now, although I'd still be interested in hearing solutions others have come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really good resource for understanding how to integrate an external authentication source is this article by Luke Taylor:

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine/

Grant